# CSS Grown Animation with Inline SVG

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

How can I make these circuits appear as if they are running downwards. I seem to have the right movement, but I can't figure out how to get them to start out their actual size, as now they appear skewed when the animation starts but then move to full size later on completion.

https://jsfiddle.net/fs4e38cz/

```
#Fill-1,
#Fill 2.... {
  -webkit-animation-name: circuitGrow;
  animation-name: circuitGrow;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes circuitGrow {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
    transform: scale(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way without scale shape using translateY:

```
@keyframes circuitGrow {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
       -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update the CSS as following below:

```
@keyframes circuitGrow {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
    transform: scale(1, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```